# TinyMCE dynamic menuItems

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to create a dropdown within tinymce, where you can insert all available parameters i loaded from a backing bean. 
This is what i came up with. Sadly it doesn't work as intended. It shows the entries in the list, but they are empty...

[Dropdown is generated but doesn't contain any text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZnHY.png)

Here the code:

```
<script>
    function initQueryTinymce(){

        var menuItems = [];

        $.each("#{queryManagementBean.getParameterList()}".replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(","), function(index, value) {
            item = {
                'text': value,
                onclick: function(){
                    editor.insertContent("{P-" + value + "}");
                }
            };
            menuItems.push(item);
        });


        tinymce.init({
            selector : '.certificateTextTinymce',
            toolbar : 'undo redo mybutton',
            menubar : false,
            statusbar : false,
            height : 100,

            //Das Paste Plugin wird benötigt damit kopierter Text (z.B. aus Word) unformatiert in den Editor geladen wird
            //Ansonten hat man z.B. unerwünschte p-Tags, Schriftarten oder sonstiges drin
            plugins: "paste",
            paste_as_text: true,

            setup: function(editor) {
                editor.addButton('mybutton', {
                      type: 'menubutton',
                      text: 'Add parameter',
                      icon: false,
                      menu: menuItems
                    });
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: `console.log(value)` in the loop and see if you get the right values

Comment: I figured out the problem... var is missing before the item object within the foreach loop :)